# Go json array of arrays

Tags: arrays, json, go

I've troubles with parsing json array of arrays using golang, all of them without names:

```
[[1594561500000, 1031.47571376], [1594562500000, 1031.43571376],[1595561500000, 1041.41376]]
```

Could you help me with it?

Comment: `var v [][]float64; json.Unmarshal(input,&v)`

Comment: ./prog.go:17:35: cannot use dataJson (type string) as type []byte in argument to json.Unmarshal

Comment: I suggest you read some introductory material on Go and its type system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget to convert the string you use to hold the JSON to `[]byte` first:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    s := []byte(`[[1594561500000, 1031.47571376], [1594562500000, 1031.43571376],[1595561500000, 1041.41376]]`)
    var nums [][]float64

    if err := json.Unmarshal(s, &nums); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(nums)
}
```

[Try it on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/TZznPTOokLo).